# $(document).on() in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, addeventlistener, mutation-observers

In jQuery there is [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which can be used as:

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function() { /* ... */ });
```

This listens for click events on all DOM elements with the class `.foo`.
However, this also listens for any eventual elements added to the DOM later, so it is not equal to:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
for (var element in elements) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() { /* ... */ });
}
```

How do I do this in plain JavaScript? Am I supposed to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)? If so, then how? If not, then what?

Comment: Without looking at the jquery source (which is "plain JavaScript"), I suspect it adds a listener to `document` then uses sizzle to check that the event source matches the selector.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That called event delegation, in the pure javascript you could attach the click event to the parent element then on click check if the clicked element match the target you want to click and perform the action you want ,like the example below :

```
document.getElementById("parent-item").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // e.target is the clicked element!
      // If it was an item with class 'foo'
      if(e.target && e.target.className == "foo") {
         console.log("foo "+e.target.innerText+" was clicked!");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
document.getElementById("parent-item").innerHTML += "<li class='foo'>Item 3</li>";

document.getElementById("parent-item").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target && e.target.className == "foo") {
    console.log("foo "+e.target.innerText+" was clicked!");
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="parent-item">
  <li class='foo'>Item 1</li>
  <li class='foo'>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: An interesting thing to note is that with event delegation it is trickier for the developer to know what will DOM element interaction with trigger an event since the Developer Tools in the web browser does not indicate so in a clear way. When you directly listen to an event then it shows an icon in the DOM tree inspector for that. Interestingly the jQuery way of doing it somehow binds each element uniquely so they show up in the developer tools.

Comment: Yes that true Fred.

Comment: If the answer is what you're looking for mark it as correct for the future readers, Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem, nice use of the event delegation !