# How can i edit the style of elements created in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to change the style of the second div-element from the innerHTML when i click on the img, but this doesnt work.

```
     function display(restaurantArr, name){
     title.innerHTML = `<h2>Available restaurants in ${name}:`
     for(let items of restaurantArr){
       console.log(items)

       main.innerHTML += `
        <div class="container">
            <p class="containerP">${items.restaurant.name}</p>
            <img onclick="editDiv2()" id="imageid" class="imgAdd" src="pngwave.png">
        </div>

        <div id="someid" class="container2">
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    `

}
```

}

The function where i tried to edit the second div. Although i understand why this doesnt work, it is a visualisation of what i tried to do:

```
function editDiv2(){
    const div2 = document.querySelector('.div2')
    div2.style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: maybe it's just typo, but the function of onClick is `div2()`, and the function you give is `editDiv2` XD

Comment: yeah, that was a typo...

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: I am calling it at the end of another function that is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```js
display([{
  restaurant: {
    name: 'Restaurant Name'
  }
}], 'London')

function display(restaurantArr, name) {
  title.innerHTML = `<h2>Available restaurants in ${name}:`
  
  for (let items of restaurantArr) {
    console.log(items)

    main.innerHTML += `
      <div class="container">
          <p class="containerP">${items.restaurant.name}</p>
          <img onclick="editDiv2()" id="imageid" class="imgAdd" src="pngwave.png">
      </div>

      <div id="someid" class="container2">
          <p>Test</p>
          <p>Test</p>
          <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    `
  }
}



function editDiv2() {
  const div2 = document.querySelector('#someid')
  div2.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<h2 id="title"></h2>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: yeah, but i forgot to show that the main.innerHTML is inside a function, i updated it now

Comment: @Mr.Ulis how are you calling your function?

Comment: From this function: <code>async function getResturant(id, name){
    const response = await fetch(`https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=${id}&entity_type=city&q=*RESTAURANT_URL*&category=7%2C9`, options);
    const data = await response.json()
    
    display(data.restaurants, name)
}</code> And that fucntion is called from onclick from a button

Comment: yes, but it only works on the first <div id="someid">. This is inside a loop so there are multiple divs and images like this, however only the first one works.

Comment: For instance, if i click on the third iteration of <img id="imageid"... it will change the color for the first iteration of div2, not the third iteration.

Comment: But i fixed it with an idea. instead of every iteration of div having id="someid", i made a divCounter++ inside the loop and added it to the divs so that there is a difference

Answer (score 1):

```
<img onclick="div2()"
```

should be

```
<img onclick="editDiv2()"
```

Or the editDiv2 function will not get called.

Comment: onclick="div2()" was a typo sorry, but not the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
    display()      
    clickEvent()    
})(); 

function display(){
        main = document.getElementById("div1")
    main.innerHTML = '<div class="container"><p class="containerP">${items.restaurant.name}</p><img id="imageid" class="imgAdd" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/330px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"></div><div id="someid" class="container2"><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p></div>'
}

function clickEvent(){

    var image = document.getElementById("imageid")
        image.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const div2 = document.querySelector('.container2')
    div2.style.color = "red";
})

}
```

Where ever you call your display function add a new function for your task and call it below display so it can register dom element its click event listner.

Here is the updated fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/3h61jdfv/

Comment: i dont use jquery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613527/document-on-in-plain-javascript

Comment: Above link is how you can convert this code to javascript one. Let me grab a computer now. My mobile can handle it anymore

Comment: If i use the method on the link you gave me, I can change the style of the e.target that i click on (the img), but i dont know how i can make it change the style of the second div, because i wont be clicking on that. Basically i want the div2 (second div) style to change when i click on the image.

Comment: Yes, that works, however the innerHTML code is inside a function, so i dont think i can accsess the elements like that. Can i paste the full code into the jsfiddle to show you?

Comment: Yes paste you can access any dom element

Comment: Ok let me see in between my dinner

Comment: hmmm, well i updated the main code at the top of this page so that it includes the whole function, so you can just look at that one.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3h61jdfv/ here's update fiddle you can add both function in document ready function

Answer (score 0):

As this is created dynamically you need to add event dynamically to

add an ID to the Image

```
<img id="image" class="imgAdd" src="pngwave.png">
```

then write a click function

```
const image = document.getElementById("image")

image.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const div2 = document.querySelector('.div2')
    div2.style.color = "red";
})
```

Comment: Would this work if the dynamicly created elements are in a loop?

Comment: Yeah , It should. but then querySelector will only change the style of first element, If you need to change the style of all then you need to use querySelectorAll