# How I can rewrite this Jquery code into Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I mentioned in the title, How can i rewrite this Jquery Code into Vanilla JS

Here's Jquery Code Example:

```html
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function())
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps start by researching how to bind an event to a class in pure JS?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$(document).on() in plain JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613527/document-on-in-plain-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is how VanillaJS snippet could look like

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.btn')) return;
    event.preventDefault();
    // Your code
}, false);
```

or if You prefer to attach click handler to specific element

```
var clickMe = document.querySelector('.click-me');
clickMe.addEventListener('click', function (event) {    // Dosomething... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `querySelector` function which is similar to the `$` in jQuery and add the desired listener using the `addEventListener`. If you want a list of all elements of the `btn` class you can use the `querySelectorAll` function.

See documentation here:

- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).